# How to know how much space is occupied by events

Tags: event

is there any way to identify how much space is occupied by events prior to 1st of Jan 2021 and have subject line starting with some specific text like 'test'

Comment: Questions that can be answered with a simple yes/no tend not to be a great fit for this site. A better approach would be for you to do some research first, and then include that in your question (if and when you get stuck).

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is yes.

Every record in Salesforce utilizes 2kB of your alloted data storage space in Salesforce (with a few exceptions like `EmailMessage` where the `textBody` and `HtmlBody` fields are fully counted towards the storage limit, and things like `ContentVersion` which consume space from your "file" storage allocation).

So if you know how many records you have, it's simple math to figure out how much storage they're consuming.

There is more than one approach you can take to get that number (SOQL query, using a tool like Data Loader, etc...)